# ag-grid's agSelectCellEditor doesn't render the cell correctly

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am using agSelectCellEditor to imlement a dropdown menu in a particular column cells.
This is the column definition:

```
{
      headerName: "Rattachement",
      field: "rattachement",
      editable: true,
      headerTooltip:
        "Choisissez l'entité de rattachement parmi les choix présents dans la liste déroulante",
      cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
      cellEditorParams: {
        values: [
          "",
          "Audit",
          "RA",
          "Consulting",
          "FA",
          "Tax&Legal",
          "ICS",
          "Taj"
        ]
      }
    }
```

This is how ag-grid renders it:
[image]
I have to doubl-click on it in order for the dropdown list to show-up this way:
[image]
And then I can select any of the available options.
As you notice, this is really poor rendering and may cause the user to be confused and unable to use the tool that I am building.

So my question is:

Is there any way to make ag-grid show the dropdown menu from the beginnig without having to double-click on the cell so that the user actually knows what to do?
Thanks!

PS: I don't want to use a custom cell renderer, because the options in the cell depend on other variables and the whole thing may get messy if I choose to implement the dropdown list using a customcellRenderer (which I did with other columns where it doesn't cause me any of the mentioned trouble)

Answer (score 2):

This is the same issue which i encountered :). 
By default AgGrid doesnt show dropdown columns. If you wish to show it as a dropdown you will have to use `cellRenderer` just to show the image to notify user that this is dropdown column.

Double click edit can be changed to singleclick or no click edit that option is avaiable. 
Set columndef option `singleClickEdit : true,`

[image: DropDown Column]

[image]

```
 var columnDefs = [
        {field: 'name', width: 100},
        {
            field: 'gender',
            width: 90,
            cellRenderer: 'genderCellRenderer',
            cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
            singleClickEdit : true,
            cellEditorParams: {
                values: ['Male', 'Female'],
            }
        },]

var gridOptions = {
    components: {
        'genderCellRenderer': GenderCellRenderer
    },
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
}

    function GenderCellRenderer() {
    }

    GenderCellRenderer.prototype.init = function (params) {
        this.eGui = document.createElement('span');
        this.eGui.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M5 8l4 4 4-4z"/></svg>' + params.value;
    };

    GenderCellRenderer.prototype.getGui = function () {
        return this.eGui;
    };
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/rOyzzRX2rpKyYEap09LD?p=preview)

Hope this helps.